# Scanning through string array

Tags: c#

I am new to C#.

How do I take user input and save each letter I type as a separate entity in an array.

I want to scan through the array and find a particular sequence of characters to act as a starting point.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter Nitrogenous base sequence");
            string[] sequence = new string[]{Console.ReadLine()};

            foreach(string a in sequence)
            {
                if(a=="TATAAT")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("YAAY");
                }

                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("NO");
```

Comment: I think you might want to be using Console.ReadKey instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of a `string` as a glorified character array.

```
var pattern = "TATAAT";
var input = Console.ReadLine();

var patternIndex = input.IndexOf(pattern);

if(patternIndex >= 0) {
  var answer = input.Substring(patternIndex + pattern.Length, 4);
  Console.WriteLine("YAAY: " + answer);

} else {
  Console.WriteLine("NO");

}
```

Comment: need to save the next four characters after "TATAAT" as a seperate entity. Do I need to make my original input string a string array and then use indexing?

Comment: thanks alot, where do you find all these sub methods?

Comment: On the [System.String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN page

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `LINQ`, this will get the input from user then save each character as `string` into an array:

```
string[] sequence = Console.ReadLine().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

If you don't want to include spaces:

```
string[] sequence = Console.ReadLine().Where(x => !char.IsWhiteSpace(x))
                    .Select(x => x.ToString())
                    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Obviously, the op is a beginner - hitting him with lambdas and LINQ requires more explanation...

Comment: still finding it tough to scan.Need to be able to type a random combination of letters and then stop when it finds TATAAT.